# How can I prefix each line with `>`

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a quote function on this forum I'm making, when I press quote I'm simply filling the `textarea` with the markdown, but the only thing is I need to prefix the markdown on each line with `>` so that it's a quote.

```
$('.quotePost').on('click', function(e) {
   let quotePostId = $(this).data('quote-id'); 
   let quoteBlock = rawMarkDown.find(x => (x.id === `quote-id-${quotePostId}`));
   console.log(quoteBlock.md);
   $('#replyBox').val(quoteBlock.md);
});
```

This is all I have so far.

e.g. of the quoted strings:

```
> > #HEY
> > 
> > This is a test!
```

so if I hit quote on this it would turn into

```
> > > #HEY
> > > 
> > > This is a test!
```

Comment: you can use _replace_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [replace function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
quoteBlock.md.replace(/^/gm, '> ')
```

```js
document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = document.getElementById('t').value.replace(/^/gm, '> ');
```

```html
<textarea id="t">
> > #HEY 
> > 
> > This is a test!</textarea>
<pre id='r'>
</pre>
```